# How can I make the value of an indicator appear in an alert message?

Tags: alert, pine-script, indicator

as the title suggests I would like to have info on how to make the value of an indicator appear in an alert message. In a nutshell, I need that in the message appear in addition to the price of eur / usd, also the value of the atr when the alert is triggered, so that I can set my SL and TP. It would also be amazing if once you understood this, it was even possible to do transactions like eurusd price minus 2 * atr, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `tostring` function to add values in the alert message.

Example from reference manual:

```
//@version=4
study("`alert()` example", "", true)
ma = sma(close, 14)
xUp = crossover(close, ma)
if xUp
    // Trigger the alert the first time a cross occurs during the real-time bar.
    alert("Price (" + tostring(close) + ") crossed over MA (" + tostring(ma) +  ").", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
plot(ma)
plotchar(xUp, "xUp", "▲", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

Same logic for your atr formula output values.

More examples:
https://kodify.net/tradingview/alerts/plot-alerts-text/